# Spring Data repo not returning updated @version from save method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In a Spring Boot 1.3.0 application, I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

I have this service method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public BookDto updateBook(BookDto bookDto) {
        BookId id = new BookId(bookDto.getId());
        if (!exists(id)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Unable to find a book with id " + bookDto.getId());
        }
        return convertToDto(bookRepository.save(bookDto.convertToBook()));
    }
```

In my entity, I have a @Version field:

```
@Version
private long version;
```

(with getter and setter) and I also have this in my DTO (without the @Version annotation on my DTO).

The 'Book' entity coming back from the `bookRepository.save()` call still has `version = 0`, instead of `1` as expected. When I do a `findAll` on the repository afterwards, the version is updated fine. What could be reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is a transaction, commit is happening after return statement. Changes are persisted in database while committing the transaction in this case. As you are not flushing explicitly, changes reflect in database only after commit. And before commit operation you are mapping the current state of entity to DTO.

**Solution 1**

If your spring repository is extending JpaRepository then you can do the following.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public BookDto updateBook(BookDto bookDto) {
    BookId id = new BookId(bookDto.getId());
    if (!exists(id)) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Unable to find a book with id " + bookDto.getId());
    }
    return convertToDto(bookRepository.saveAndFlush(bookDto.convertToBook()));
}
```

**Solution 2**

Another solution without explicit flushing: move the conversion of entity to dto outside the updateBook() method. Use some other helper function to map entity to dto. Reason is because entities are in sync with database after commit operation if there is no explicit flush. But you are mapping them to DTO before the transaction is committed. So move the entity to DTO mapping to some mapper class or do it in the service layer.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public BookEntity updateBook(BookDto bookDto) {
    BookId id = new BookId(bookDto.getId());
    if (!exists(id)) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Unable to find a book with id " + bookDto.getId());
    }
    return bookRepository.save(bookDto.convertToBook());
}

// call this method to map book entity to dto
public BookDTO mapToDTO(BookEntity){
    return bookDTO;
}
```

Comment: This method is in my `BookService` which is used by my `BookController`. Are you saying that it is better to work with `BookEntity` in my service and do the DTO conversions in the controller?

Comment: no. i did not mean that. there are different ways this can be achieved. you can create another layer so your service layer talks to this layer. why we are creating these additional layers because spring works on proxies as otherwise transaction would not work. If you dont want extra classes you can use flush. I just gave different solutions. You can choose the best one that suits. I would suggest not to have entity at Controller.

Comment: plz, can you accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: I ended up putting the conversion in my controller as is done here: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application